# A WinAmp-like music player for Linux?

Tags: music, media-player

I like WinAmp, I'm used to WinAmp. I'm not saying every single aspect of it is wonderful, but it's gotten enough right to keep me a loyal user.

Now, QMMP - at least on my GNU/Linux Mint 18.3 - has (at least) three annoying bugs/misfeatures:

- Poor/no support for Unicode in filenames
- Trouble with minimization/maximization, where only one of the several panes will become visible again, and it's hella difficult to make the others reappear.
- Lacking higher-resolution skins

So I'm looking for another player. Requirements:

- WinAmp-like
- Gratis and libre
- Actively maintained
- Doesn't exhibit glaring bugs

Desirable:

- Multi-file tagging / tag editing capability
- Ability to rename files by tags and patterns
- Ability to fix invalid charset use in meta-data fields (essentially applying `tr` or a regexp to various fields in many files)
- Different erfrom QMMP/WinAmp in non-intrusive/interesting ways I might appreciate despite my "conservatism"

Undesirable:

- Trying to be general-purpose media player

PS - If you were to tell me QMMP's trunk is better than what I have installed - I'll take that as one of the possible answers.

Comment: Did you try Amarok and Clementine? They're the best as far as I know.

Comment: @onurcano22: Amarok is really not like WinAmp. Clementine - I remember hearing about it.

Comment: What's wrong with VLC?  That said, you might want to look at `xmms` - it was modeled on WinAmp.  Dunno if it really whips a llama's butt though...

Comment: @ivanivan: There's nothing wrong with it, it's just not like WinAmp.

Answer (score 3):

[Audacious](https://audacious-media-player.org/) is a relatively simple, lightweight audio player - similar in function to WinAmp 2.x. It supports, as an option, using a WinAmp-like skinnable interface:

[image]

You can [read about it on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Audacious_(software)) as well.

It uses the [FreeBSD license ("2-clause BSD license")](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BSD_licenses#2-clause_license_(%22Simplified_BSD_License%22_or_%22FreeBSD_License%22)). Hopefully no glaring bugs, and latest release (at the time of writing) in August 2017, so reasonably-actively maintained.

Comment: Audacious isn't an equivalent to Winamp.

Comment: @onurcano22: It's not an equivalent, but its UI is WinAmp-like. But you're very welcome to edit my answer and list some aspects of difference from WinAmp which you think are significant.